# Dar insert em outra tabela

Tags: php

if (isset($_POST['menu'])) {

```
$menu = $_POST['menu'];

$delivery = null;
if (isset($_POST['delivery'])) {
    $delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
}
$cards = null;
if (isset($_POST['cards'])) {
    $cards = $_POST['cards'];
}
$wifi = null;
if (isset($_POST['wifi'])) {
    $wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
}
$music = null;
if (isset($_POST['music'])) {
    $music = $_POST['music'];
}
$holiday = null;
if (isset($_POST['holiday'])) {
    $holiday = $_POST['holiday'];
}
$acessible = null;
if (isset($_POST['acessible'])) {
    $acessible = $_POST['acessible'];
}
$address = null;
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];
}

$dateFoundation = null;
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $dateFoundation = $_POST['date'];
}
$cnpj = null;
if (isset($_POST['cnpj'])) {
    $cnpj = $_POST['cnpj'];
}
$latitude = null;
if (isset($_POST['latitude'])) {
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
}
$longitude = null;
if (isset($_POST['longitude'])) {
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
}
$link = null;
if (isset($_POST['link'])) {
    $link = $_POST['link'];
}
$site = null;
if (isset($_POST['site'])) {
    $site = $_POST['site'];
}
$facebook = null;
if (isset($_POST['facebook'])) {
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
}
$instagram = null;
if (isset($_POST['instagram'])) {
    $instagram = $_POST['instagram'];
}
$googleplus = null;
if (isset($_POST['googleplus'])) {
    $googleplus = $_POST['googleplus'];
}
$pinterest = null;
if (isset($_POST['pinterest'])) {
    $pinterest = $_POST['pinterest'];
}



$stmtMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("SELECT only_delivery, card_on_delivery, wifi, live_music, 
                                        open_holiday, acessible FROM public.menu
                                        WHERE menu_id = :menu");

$stmtMoreInformations->bindValue(":menu", $menu);



if ($stmtMoreInformations->execute()) {

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("UPDATE menu SET only_delivery = :delivery, card_on_delivery = :card,
                                                 wifi = :wifi, live_music = :music, open_holiday = :holiday, 
                                                 acessible = :acessible
                                                 WHERE menu_id = :menu");

    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':menu', $menu);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':delivery', $delivery);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':card', $cards);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':wifi', $wifi);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':music', $music);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':holiday', $holiday);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':acessible', $acessible);
    $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->execute();
}
```

Tenho um arquivo php com diversos comandos de insert e update, se executar algum deles eu tenho outra tabela aonde devo dar um insert que algo mudou. Como faço para atribuir uma variável que reconheça que devo dar insert no campo tal?

Comment: Bom nesse arquivo que você colocou você tem select e update, não identifiquei nenhum insert

Comment: Então, mas por exemplo se executar o meu update é porque alterou um dos meus inputs, então na outra tabela deve aparecer que eu alterei por exemplo $cards, o campo cards. Precisava inicializar uma variável que recebesse meus comandos. Para saber quando executei um update ou outro. No caso tenho muitos updates.

Comment: Deixe-me ver se entendi, se executar o update da variável $stmtUpdateMoreInformations, você quer realizar um outro insert em outra tabela pré definida?

Comment: Simmm e na minha outra tabela, tenho uma coluna 'field', aonde tenho que informar o que foi alterado, se foi cards, se foi wifi, etc..

Comment: @Isabela vc sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta pra ti

Comment: Ok! Vai me ajudar muito @Isabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão de executar um insert somente após executar o update é só fazer o seguinte:

```
if ($stmtMoreInformations->execute()) {

   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations = $conn->prepare("UPDATE menu SET only_delivery = :delivery, card_on_delivery = :card, wifi = :wifi, live_music = :music, open_holiday = :holiday, acessible = :acessible WHERE menu_id = :menu");

   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':menu', $menu);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':delivery', $delivery);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':card', $cards);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':wifi', $wifi);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':music', $music);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':holiday', $holiday);
   $stmtUpdateMoreInformations->bindValue(':acessible', $acessible);

   if($stmtUpdateMoreInformations->execute()){
      //Executar o teu insert normalmente, pois já executou o update
   }
}
```

Quanto a questão dos campos e identificar qual deles foi alterado, talvez tenha alguma forma melhor de se fazer, mas no momento, pensei em fazer um select antes de dar o update onde o "menu_id = :menu" e guardar os campos, depois você compara os dados, por exemplo (estou partindo do princípio que o teu select foi executado e o valor antigo de "wifi" já foi setado para a variável `$wifiOld`:

```
if($stmtUpdateMoreInformations->execute()){ //Se executou o update, faça...
   if($wifi != wifiOld){ //Se o valor usado para dar update, for diferente do antigo, faça
     //Executa o que for necessário
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada! Vou tentar.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaRibeiro Lembra de marcar a pergunta como resposta que melhor atendeu se ela resolveu o teu problema ;)

Comment: Ok vou lembrar sim @Isabela!!